# Click event data not sending to Google Analytics in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-analytics, analytics

This code works well in Chrome browser. When you clicked on "Book" Button data sends to google analytics in chrome but having issue in Firefox. I have tried both Firefox regular and Firefox developer Edition. I can read data `(retId, retName, desName)` in Firefox browser using `alert` but unable to send to Google analytics.

```
  <form>  
    <input class="btn form_submit" type="submit" value="BOOK">
  </form>
```

I haven't added `form` full form.

```
bookSubmit: function(retId, retName, desName) {
        $('.form_submit').on('click', function(e) {
            alert(retId);
            alert(retName);
            alert(desName);
        
            // ga when you click book button on checkout page
            ga('require', 'ec');
            ga('ec:addProduct', {
                'id': retId,
                'name': retName,
                'brand': 'XYZ',
                'category': desName,
                'variant': desName
            });
            var desURL = Cookies.get('des_url');
            var homeURL = Cookies.get('home_url');
            ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
                'list': desURL,
                'step': 3
            });
            ga('send', 'pageview');
            // ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout', 'Option');
        });
     });
```

Comment: Might want to do a $('.form_submit').unbind() prior to calling the event. May be the submission is already happening before your function call, or on a separate thread

Comment: @ullfindsmit I have tried  `$('.form_submit').unbind();` and `$('.form_submit').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e)` but it didn't work.

Comment: is the form_submit element an actual <form tag? if so, it might be doing the submit automatically on the button click. Alternatively, you might want to use the form's onsubmit event to send data before returning true

Comment: form_submit is input tag and inside <form> tag.

Comment: if the input tag is type="submit" it will automatically submit even with the handler. alternatively, do the unbind on document ready or check on developer console events section to see if there are other listeners